# How to use ng-model

Tags: angularjs, html

```
<input type="search" placeholder="{{'COMPONENT_PROPERTIES.SEARCH_ICON' | translate}}"
   ng-model="icon.name"
   list="classIcon"
   ng-change="changeFn(icon.name)">
<i class="{{$select.selected}}"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;
{{$select.selected}}
<datalist class="data-scrollable"
   id="classIcon"
   infinite-scroll="addMoreItems()">
   <option ng-repeat="icon in classService.classesAwesome | limitTo:infiniteScroll.currentItems track by $index ">
      <i class="{{icon}}"></i> &nbsp;
      <span ng-bind-html="icon | highlight: icon.name "></span>
   </option>
</datalist>
```

I define `ng-model="icon.name"` in input, and how to use it to highlight the option that matches with the `ng-model` value?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to use icon.name outside input

Comment: so u want to access value of icon.name(i.e.  ng-model=icon.name) inside the ng-repeater ? if so  use this <option ng-repeat="_incon in classService.classesAwesome | limitTo:infiniteScroll.currentItems track by $index ">
                <i class="{{_icon}}"></i> &nbsp;
                <span ng-bind-html="_icon | highlight: icon.name "></span>
            </option>

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` create its own child `scope` so you can't use the `parent scope` variable directly into this `child scope`. You have to access the `parent scope` properties with `$parent` means in your case just try

```
<span ng-bind-html="icon | highlight: $parent.icon.name "></span>
```